# extract data from Google Docs into Google Sheets using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Looking for a Doc -> Sheets script.

I have about 300 Google Doc files with some similar parts that I'd like to extract some data from into a Google Sheet.  (For example, they have an address on the first page and the person's name and I'd like to only extract the address and names and not the rest of the Doc)

I'd like to have a script or other automated way of reading in the information sequentially from all 300 Google Docs so I can have the relevant part extracted and saved to a Google Sheet. (Exporting each file individually will take far too long)

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `I have about 300 Google Doc files with some similar parts that I'd like to extract some data from into a Google Sheet. I'd like to have a script or other automated way (saving each file individually will take far too long) of reading in the information so I can have the relevant part extracted.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: I added more info in my question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I'm looking for a Doc -> Sheets script.    In Doc: line 1,2,3 to column ABC in Sheets.  I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `I'm looking for a Doc -> Sheets script. I'm not sure what else to say.`, I cannot still understand your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. But I would like to support you. So I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging around and found a way to do this:  There might be an easier way of doing this but this worked for me.

```
function readGoogleDoc_writetoGoogelSheet() {
  
  // sheet with all IDs of documents
  var IDdocSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('-----doc ID goes here----');
  var IDdoc = IDdocSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Sheet tab with source data

//target sheet
  var TargetdocSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('----doc ID goes here ----');
  var Targetdoc = TargetdocSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Sheet tab with target data



    startRow = 0; // First row of data to process
    numRows = 251; // Number of rows to process

    // Fetch the range of cells into an array containing all IDs
    const dataRange = IDdoc.getRange(1, 1, numRows, 1);   //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    const data = dataRange.getValues(); 
    var text=[];

   var start=1;
   for (i=1;i<numRows; i++){
      var docID= data[i];
      Logger.log(i+"  "+docID);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);

//get body of text from the Google DOC
      const body = doc.getBody();
//convert all content to text
      var text = body.editAsText().getText();

//set up convert all lines of text (as separated by a new line character (/n)
      var line=[];
      var l=0; 
      line[l]="";
      var string="";
      var max_l=0;

      for (let j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {

        if (text[j]!="\n"){
          string=string+text[j];
        }else{ 
          line[l]=string;
          s=string;
          string="";
          l++;
        }
        //I cust off when I find some text in my document... in my case when the line begins with either the work "Welcome" or "Next", then I stop processing and move to the next file
        if((l>2) && ( (s.substring(0, 7)=="Welcome") || (s.substring(0, 4)=="Next"))){max_l=l-3;break;}
      }
      
//write relevant daate to targetspreadsheet
      for (let l = 0; l < max_l; l++) {
          if(   line[l].search(/---text to find----/)>0 ){
            var insertpart=line[l].substring(line[l].search(/---text to find----/)+8, line[l].length);
              var cell = Targetdoc.getRange("A"+start);
              cell.setValue(insertpart);

              start+=1;
          }
      }
   }
}
```